Crow C++ websocket sending data
I am creating a chat app that will pass data through a GNU radio flowgraph and back to the app. I am using a websocket connection between my frontend and backend. Currently I have a function that receives the message, how do I send that data to the frontend and display it.
//crow server 
int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unordered_set<crow::websocket::connection*> users; 
    crow::SimpleApp app; //define your crow application

    char buf[256]; //data to be sent to frontend
    std::thread recThread(gnu::recMessages, buf);
   
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t sender(ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
    sender.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:50261");

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/scripts/<string>")
        ([](const request& req, response& res, string filename) {
        sendScript(res, filename);
            });
   
    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/ws")
        .websocket()
        .onopen([&](crow::websocket::connection& conn) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex>_(mtx);
            users.insert(&conn);
            })
        .onclose([&](crow::websocket::connection& conn, const string &reason) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex>_(mtx);
                users.erase(&conn);
            })
        .onmessage([&](crow::websocket::connection& conn, const string &data, bool is_binary) {
        for (auto user : users) {
            if (is_binary) {
                user->send_binary(data);
            }
            else {
                gnu::sendMessages(conn, data, sender);
            }
        }
            });

      CROW_ROUTE(app, "/chat")
            ([](const request& req, response& res) {
            sendHtml(res, "chat");
            });
    //set the port, set the app to run on multiple threads, and run the app
    app.port(18080).multithreaded().run();
}

